# Webpack + Babel + ES 2015 Unexpected token import on browser

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

This question is though already asked here:
[webpack + babel - react, unexpected token 'import'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389468/webpack-babel-react-unexpected-token-import)

But I am asking this again as I could not resolve using the answers provided.

I am not able to get this working. Any help on pointing to what is wrong here is appreciated. I am setting up webpack with es-2015 for first time.

It is still throwing same error Unexpected token import on browser

my babelrc file

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

webpack.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
entry: './app.js',
output: {
    path: './bin',
    filename: 'app.bundle.js'
},
module: {
    loader: [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            loader: 'babel',
            query: {
              presets: ['es2015']
            }
        }
    ]
}
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your config looks fine. Are you using the latest versions on Node/NPM? Upgrade to Node 6.3 & npm 3.10.3 and `rm -rf node_modules | npm i`.

Vagrant sometimes causes this issue as well, due to a bug in VirtualBox. The solution, is to set `sendfile off;` in your nginx config, or `EnableSendfile Off` if you use Apache.